# Copy-on-write-if-leaked idiom in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, copy-on-write

I have a situation where I must generate a sequence of objects, and pass them back to an application one at a time (think block-based, or fast enumeration).

However, each object is going to be relatively expensive to generate, so I am looking for ways to avoid this cost.

It happens to be the case, that given one object of the sequence, the next one can be efficiently generated by a simple modification of the former. For this reason, it is tempting to "cheat" by only ever creating one object, and then keep passing that same object back to the application, and only carrying out the "cheap" modification "behind the scene" at each step in the sequence.

The problem is, of course, that the application may choose to (and it should be allowed to) store a reference to some, or all of the objects somewhere else. If it does that, the "illusion" of a true sequence of unique objects breaks down.

If Objective-C allows it, a neat way of solving this problem would be to detect when the application actually does store references elsewhere, and whenever that happens, replace the object by a copy of itself, before applying the modification that produce the next element in the sequence.

I don't know what the official name of this idiom is, but we could call it "copy on write if leaked", "copy on write if shared", or simply "copy on write".

My question is then: Does Objective-C, with ARC enabled, allow for such an idiom to be implemented?

And, is it even the right way to solve this kind of problem in Objective-C?

I did notice that with ARC enabled, there is no way I can extract the reference count from an object, nor override the methods that increment and decrement it.

---

EDIT: I have noticed that there is a `copy` attribute that can be applied to properties, but I have a hard time figuring it out. Are any of you guys able to explain how it works?

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations

Comment: Sounds like you might have to get involved with the reference count in order to implement this, which is very much discouraged.  It's not so much copy-on-write as the calling code might just want to keep the objects for the purposes of comparison.  Imagine their surprise then the properties of those object changes behind the scenes.  Good luck, I think you have a hard road to tread.

Comment: What is expensive about creating the object? Why not have some sort of copy initializer that generates your updated object by copying the existing one and doing the modification like that? You really don't want to get into mucking with reference count or anything like that...

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, the nontrivial part of "copy on write if leaked" is "if leaked" :-)

Comment: @Chris The expense of creating a new object is the dynamic allocation of the object + the initialization of quite a number of properties. On the other hand, the alternative is to update a single integer variable. This could work because the function of the properties are controlled by a combination of fixed information in those properties, and that single integer.

Comment: Do you have to actually modify that heavy object? if you can apply those modifications on the fly (without mutating the source), return cheap proxies all sharing the same big object

Comment: @hamstergene The objects are already proxies. And, we are not talking about hugely expensive construction here. Just a desire to cut down the cost of proxy object creation. If Objective-C has something available for implementing the "copy on write if leaked", then that would likely speed up iteration by a lot.

Comment: How about a contract where the thing that wants to keep a reference to it (the 'leak') is responsible for making a copy of it? That way it's only "copy on leak" as you're desiring. I will emphasize this: You're not likely to find a solution baked into the language - go back to some more general object management ideas that aren't language specific.